# Query mongodb to search count occurrence of lats and lngs in collection

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with following details..

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("58fa2847a105621bf28c7436"), 
        "srcLoc" : [ 29.03596937656403, 41.08048413380768 ], 
        "destLoc" : [ 29.3168603, 40.905371 ], 
        "wayPoints" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("58fa2961de50171c2e89e4e2"),
             "lng" : 29.035865853970662,
              "lat" : 41.08010057266194 
            },
            { "_id" : ObjectId("58fa2961de50171c2e89e4e1"), 
             "lng" : 29.053879848358697, 
             "lat" : 41.082083123947546 
            },
            { "_id" : ObjectId("58fa2961de50171c2e89e4e0"), 
             "lng" : 29.0638848389565, 
             "lat" : 41.0857235683904 
            },
            { "_id" : ObjectId("58fa2961de50171c2e89e4df"), 
             "lng" : 29.03194416492813, 
             "lat" : 41.0566495985393 
            } 
        ],
        "totalDistance" : 0.004627394567308733,
        "driverId" : ObjectId("58ecd6a563b5128b2b5e298b"),
        "riderId" : ObjectId("58ececcbb5e88b94e59e0cd1"),
        "__v" : 0 
        }
```

here field "wayPoints" has  intermediate points lats-lngs pair. And I have to find which lat-lng pair comes most of times in wayPoints field throughtout the collection... For eg. I assume a lat-lng pair from wayPoints field 
    [ "lng" : 29.035865853970662,
      "lat" : 41.08010057266194 ]
I need to count occurence of this lat-lng pair in all wayPoints fields belong to the collection.

Comment: Could you please refine the question with an example of what documents in your collection look like and a clear example of what your input data and expected result are?

Comment: I have documents with following details..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this aggregation framework query:

```
db.stackoverflow.aggregate(
[
    {$unwind: "$wayPoints"},
    {$group: 
        {
        _id: {lng:"$wayPoints.lng", lat:"$wayPoints.lat"},
        count: {$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {count:-1}}
]
)
```

I created some documents like the one you provided then I ran this query on the collection and the result is the following. You can see that for each lat-lng pair there is a counter of its occurrences and they are sorted starting from the most popular pair (3 occurrences).

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 29.035865853970662, 
        "lat" : 41.08010057266194
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(3)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 29.0638848389565, 
        "lat" : 41.0857235683904
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 29.053879848358697, 
        "lat" : 41.08208312394755
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 29.03194416492813, 
        "lat" : 41.0566495985393
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(2)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 49.0638848389565, 
        "lat" : 61.0857235683904
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 39.0538798483587, 
        "lat" : 51.08208312394755
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "lng" : 59.03194416492813, 
        "lat" : 71.0566495985393
    }, 
    "count" : NumberInt(1)
}
```